# How can I schedule a nightly reboot?

Tags: debian, cron, reboot

I'm having some periodic issues running a particular application.

I know a scheduled reboot is NOT the answer but until I can figure out the problem I need to schedule a reboot each morning.

Any takers?

```
  Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
  Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64
  Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: You have tagged your question with [tag:cron]. Have you tried scheduling the reboot with `cron`?

Comment: And do you want to reboot a guest machine or the host machine or both?